# When a baby grows up into a toddler can I change its outfit?

Tags: tomodachi-life

I saw this video and someone's Mii's toddler was wearing something I saw in the clothes shop. Just to be sure can a toddler on Tomodachi Life wear clothes from the clothes shop?

Answer (score 1):

No they can't, except in the photo studio.

Answer (score -1):

Actually no! Nobody can give a toddler a clothing from the clothes shop!